# Why is this query being logged as slow_query?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have the following database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `musics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `slug` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `added` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `featured` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `hits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `slug` (`slug`),
  KEY `active` (`active`),
  KEY `featured` (`featured`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3339 ;
```

And the query `UPDATE musics SET hits = 7 WHERE id =  '1770'` gets run on each page load of a music album. Is there any way to optimize this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like the mysql docs say:
"The slow query log consists of SQL statements that took more than long_query_time seconds to execute" -> long_query_time is a Server System Variable from mysql, which could also be changed.

to the optimization-question:

you could write " = 1770" without ' because thats an integer and not a string

Answer (score 1):

example..

```
set global long_query_time=1;
```

and, my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
...
long_query_time=1;
```

and you can use 'explain'.

```
explain select * from musics where id = 1770;
```